# Connecting machines remotely. How to execute .exe on a remote machine that is only connected via USB to another remote networked machine?

Tags: windows, sas, admin, remote-access, remote-desktop

**I have three machines as follows**:

- Machine A with Win 10 and admin rights at home
- Machine B with Win 10 and no admin rights at office behind a firewall
- Machine C with Win 10 and admin rights that I hope to connect to Machine B

**My existing setup is as follows**:

- I run a VPN (Pulse Connect) on Machine A, and then execute Remote Desktop Connection on Machine A to connect to Machine B
- Do all my work on Machine B. I never copy any files from Machine B to Machine A, and vice-versa

**My problem**:

- I need to analyze Machine B sensitive data on a software that cannot be installed on Machine B (i.e. SAS JMP). I can install SAS JMP either on Machine A or Machine C. Machine C is currently not connected anywhere

**Proposed solution from my Office IS**:

- Machine B has sensitive data that can only be analyzed with software that exists in Machine C
- Office IS advised me to normalize Machine B's sensitive data, transfer it over VPN to Machine A, transfer it over to Machine C, and then run the software (i.e. SAS JMP), and transfer results back to Machine B, apply normalization key to re-identify data ***NOTE***: I don't like this solution because it is extremely cumbersome, limits my ability to "play with the data", and is also error prone

**Questions**:

(1) Is there a scenario where I could connect Machine C to Machine B via USB/other, and then from Machine A VPN to Machine B, transfer sensitive data to Machine C (with no normalization), and then run my analysis on Machine C using SAS JMP that resides on Machine C?

(2) Other scenarios you think might be helpful?

Thank you in advance. My apologies ahead of time for my ignorance and potentially leaving out any critical information you need to opine. Please let me know if that is the case. Thanks again!

Comment: I don't think that's a programming question but rather one of system administration and/or regular use. Consider asking in superuser.com instead, but this time read the site guidelines first!

Comment: I do this scenario currently. The way I handle is to submit using a web service running on the machines and routing jobs. that said, it is a bit too much for you to do if you aren't familiar with the tech stack. Consider looking at PSEXEC in SysInternals. Use PowerShell and remote execute. What you are asking for is more than possible.

Comment: Also, Win 10 now includes SSH which can do this as well. Consider that possibility.